# .htaccess SEF URL is not working if /component used in the URL for Joomla

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla3.0, httpd.conf

When site is using the alias for Seo-friendly URL then it is working fine.

http://SITEURL/member-login

but when site is using the URL like "/component/girls" then it is not working and giving the error "Bad karma: we can't find that page!".

http://SITEURL/component/girls/girls/viewcart?lang=en

Below is the .htaccess file:

```
    ##
    # @package    Joomla
    # @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
    # @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
    ##

    ##
    # READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
    #
    # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
    # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
    # be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
    # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
    # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
    # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
    ##

    ## No directory listings
    #IndexIgnore *

    ## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ## Mod_rewrite in use.

    RewriteEngine on

    ## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
    # If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
    # This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
    #
    # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
    # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
    #
    ## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

    ## Begin - Custom redirects
    #
    # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
    # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
    # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
    #
    ## End - Custom redirects

    ##
    # Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
    # is not directly related to physical file paths.
    # Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
    ##

    RewriteBase /

    ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
    #
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

    # and the request is for something within the component folder,
    # or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
    # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    #
    ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Please suggest, what I am missing? Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

/component/girls is not being matched by your `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]`

Also note it has a query_string and to match those you would need a RewriteCond specific for Query String.

Note that all those RewriteCond checks for non existant files and directories and the resulting rewriterule could most times be changed for a single directive:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Also, avoid .htaccess if you are the admin. It adds unnecessary overhead and adds lots of complexity associated with defining per-dir configurations.